# Spying udp packets in windows with wireshark

Tags: windows, udp, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, spying

I have to capture udp packets coming and leaving port 44301 and 45301. Problem is that my process manager says that there is packet transfer in and out, but my wireshark doesn't find that udp communication, when I try to search activity for that port. So if you got any ideas that what may cause this, please reply. PS the executable witch sends those packets is a windows service if that's important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that wireshark cannot access localhost line, so I must use another packet sniffer.